# Generate live instance of webpage (including live user inputted data) to new unique url

Tags: javascript, php, html

Many online IDEs offer the facility to click a button and it generates a new unique URL containing a live instance of the webpage, the moment the button was clicked. For example jsfiddle.

I wonder if anyone could help shed light on the easiest way to implement this facility.

EDIT

To clarify further, this online ide https://create.withcode.uk/, once you have written some code you can click the share button and choose to save to a new URL. This site will create a unique URL for that instance of the page including the code added by the user.

Sometimes this facility is known as a remix.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what exactly you are doing, or if you would just like to know how jsfiddle in particular works?

Comment: So, for example this online ide https://create.withcode.uk/, once you have written some code you can click the share button and choose to save to a new URL. This site will create a unique URL for that instance of the page including the code added by the user.

Comment: Just save the data in your database alongside a unique ID (which can be auto-generated by your database) to identify it. When that ID is used as part of the URL, your PHP code can identify it, and pull the related data from the database to display on the page. Pretty standard web app functionality, in other words. e.g. if you store the data with id `123` then if you have a php script `showcode.php`, then the user entering `showcode.php?id=123` would cause the PHP to find and display the code associated with ID 123

Comment: It only gets more complex if you want to have "clean" URLs without a querystring, e.g. `/showcode/123` instead. Then you need a routing script to parse the URL and decide what to do. But my advice would be - don't add that sort of extra complexity until you've got the basics working.

Comment: This is so helpful. So to clarify my understanding. 1 On 'saveToUrl' button click, a function is run which a. saves content of editor to dB, where id will be generated b. new ID is returned back to function c. function complete by linking to URL with ?id='returnedID' at the end. Then for the loading page I 1. add to the PHP script $_GET["ID"] to get the id from the URL 2. pass ID to dB to fetch corresponding data 3. load this fetched data to the editor. Does that logic sound about right? Thanks again.

Comment: That's pretty much exactly right, yes.

Comment: @ADyson, thank you again, I have managed to follow the logic you outlined and have it working perfectly. Now, to complete the job I wish to hide the search parameters in the URL and instead display characters to make coming back to a instance of code more user friendly. For example `url.com?id=1` might become `url.com\python\a`, `url.com?id=2` might become `url.com\python\b` and `url.com?id=52` might become `url.com\python\az`. Any direction you could give would be brilliant. Thank you again

Comment: I mentioned the general approach to doing that in my second comment. There's quite a lot of reading you can do on the topic, and a number of different ways of physically implementing such a URL routing scheme, you would need to do some research and choose an approach you believe suits your situation